# need assitance for implementing word guessing game using swing in Java?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, event-listener

I have some working code for word guessing game using Swing. Currently, after the game finishes, I need to rerun the `main` app, for starting another game. I would like to give an option for

```
New Game
 YES NO
```

I have implemented using model/controller pattern.
I am pasting here my mainapp and hangmanPane. but it has other class files which I am not including.

```
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                HangManModel model = new DefaultHangManModel("HangManGame");
                HangManPane hangManPane = new HangManPane(model);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hang Man");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(hangManPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

}

public class HangManPane extends JPanel {

    private KeyPadPane keyPadPane;
    private GuessPane guessPane;
    private HangManModel model;
    private HangManModelHandler hangManModelHandler;

    public HangManPane(HangManModel model) {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        add(getGuessPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(getKeyPadPane(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setModel(model);

    }

    public HangManPane() {

        this(null);

    }

    public void setModel(HangManModel value) {

        getKeyPadPane().setModel(value);
        getGuessPane().setModel(value);

        if (model != null) {

            model.removeHangManModelListener(getHangManModelListener());

        }

        HangManModel old = model;
        model = value;
        firePropertyChange("model", old, model);

        if (model != null) {

            model.addHangManModelListener(getHangManModelListener());

        }

    }

    protected HangManModelListener getHangManModelListener() {

        if (hangManModelHandler == null) {

            hangManModelHandler = new HangManModelHandler();

        }

        return hangManModelHandler;

    }

    protected KeyPadPane getKeyPadPane() {

        if (keyPadPane == null) {

            keyPadPane = new KeyPadPane();

        }

        return keyPadPane;

    }

    protected GuessPane getGuessPane() {

        if (guessPane == null) {

            guessPane = new GuessPane();

        }

        return guessPane;

    }

    protected class HangManModelHandler implements HangManModelListener {

        @Override
        public void newGame(HangManModelEvent evt) {
        }

        @Override
        public void wonGame(HangManModelEvent evt) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HangManPane.this, "You Won!", "Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }

        @Override
        public void lostGame(HangManModelEvent evt) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(HangManPane.this, "You Lose!", "Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        }

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(HangManModelEvent evt) {
        }

    }

}
```

P.S: StackOverflow User `MadProgrammer` actually helped in implementing most of this code.

Comment: Where's the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `HangManPane` class, you could to provide a `playAgain` method, for example...

```
protected void playAgain(String msg) {

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, 
            "<html>" + msg + "<br>Do you want to play again?", 
            "Play Agaion", 
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, 
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    switch (result) {
        case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
            setModel(new DefaultHangManModel("Your new secret word"));
            break;
        default:
            SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this).dispose();
            break;
    }

}
```

In the `HangManListener` implementation, you would simply then call this method, for example...

```
    @Override
    public void wonGame(HangManModelEvent evt) {

        playAgain("You won");

    }

    @Override
    public void lostGame(HangManModelEvent evt) {

        playAgain("You lost");

    }
```

Comment: This worked for most part. I dont this the entire model is reset, becoz I see keypadPane has some enabled (in blue) from previous game key presses. and when the game is lost, the answer doesnt fill up.

Comment: You may need to look at the `KeyPadPane` and ensure that it is resetting the buttons when the model changes. You could reveal the answer as part of a `lostGame` event in the guess pane (don't have the code in front of me)

Comment: There is this method in KeyPadPane which should reset the buttons, but it is not..`protected void resetGameState() {

  if (buttons != null) {
   
   HangManModel model = getModel();
   boolean enabled = model == null ? false : model.getState() == HangManModel.State.InProgress;
   for (AbstractButton btn : buttons) {

    btn.setEnabled(enabled);

   }

  }`

Comment: There is no `lostGame` or `WonGame` state in GuessesPane and GuessPane. There is gameStateChanged() and resetGameState() methods in `GuessesPane`. should I create a new method to have the answer revealed as part of lostGame event in `GuessPane`?. Thanks

Comment: Generally, the sub components shouldn't care, more or less.  In the `KeyPadPane`, if `enabled` is `true`, you need to set the selected state of the button to `false`, `btn.setSelected(false);` and add a `repaint` request at the end of the method.  You'll need to add `repaint` to the end of the `resetGameState` in the `GuessesPane` as well

Comment: when a new game begins, keypadPane should be enabled and it is enabled when I run. but some buttons are "highlighted", just like the "OK" button of the JOptionPane.DialogBox. I want to reset the `highligted` buttons back to normal

Comment: how to do I insert the correct answer, if the guess was wrong? I want the correct answer to be displayed. there is no lostGame or WonGame state in GuessesPane and GuessPane?

Comment: In the `GuessesPane` there is a `updateGameState` method which reacts to changes in the model state.  You could check for a `HangManModel.State.InProgress` and update the "guesses" as the method does now and `HangManModel.State.Lose` to reveal the secret word.  You could also override the the `lostGame` method from `AbstractView` if that was easier...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41584/discussion-between-user1988876-and-madprogrammer)

Comment: I left you a message in chat,

Answer (score 2):

> Currently, after the game finishes, I need to rerun the main app, for starting another game. I would like to give an option for
>
> New Game
> YES NO

Then code it.

- use a JOptionPane that asks this question.
- Give your classes `reset()` methods that can then be called if the user wants to run another game. You should be the one to create this code though.

> StackOverflow User MadProgrammer actually implemented most of this code.

Not a good idea. Borrow ideas yes, but not code.

Comment: Thanks. I understand I have to give reset() but the problem is I am not able to know where to actually put it. I mean in the code I pasted above, it should be part of 'void wonGame(HangManModelEvent evt)' and 'void wonGame(HangManModelEvent evt) ' method?  It should reset the entire application, which has about 5 or 6 classes in total..

Comment: @user1988876: if you're using MVC correctly, all you have to do is reset your model to its base conditions, and the listeners in the model should automatically reset the view.