# how to get buttons and actionlisteners to the JoptionPane attached in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, button, joptionpane

Here is the simple code that has two `JoptionPane`.
currently, it has no buttons, but I want to attach button to the second `JOptionPane` for Yes or NO event.
Moreover, when the two `JOptionPanes` are closed, the `Frame` does not close.Is there a way to force close `Frame` when `JoptionPanes` are closed.

here is my current code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TestJoption {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You Won!", "Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "yes No", "play again", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828389/actionlistener-on-joptionpane/12829264#12829264)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I have posted a question about HangManExample that you helped in building up. If you have time, can you help out there.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086180/need-assitance-for-implementing-word-guessing-game-using-swing-in-java

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "yes No", "play again", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
```

this is popup the box with yes and no options..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need next code:

```
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You Won!", "Winner", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "yes No", "play again",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
        frame.dispose();
    }
```

Also read tutorial for [dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

For closing the window you can either use

```
frame.setVisible(false);
```

or you can simply call

```
System.exit(0);
```

this will terminate your process.